# How to keep my table on one page?

Tags: tables, longtable

```
   {
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\singlespacing
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{l*{1}{c}}
\hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{pobreza}\\
\hline
conyuge             &       0.433\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0782)         \\
hijos               &       0.237\sym{***}\\
                    &   (0.00954)         \\
%omitida en arriendo         &           0         \\
%omitida                    &         (.)         \\
anticresis y/o arriendo&      -0.210         \\
                    &     (0.150)         \\
propia y la está pagando&     -0.0977\sym{*}  \\
                    &    (0.0433)         \\
propia y totalmente pagada&     -0.0287         \\
                    &    (0.0199)         \\
cedida              &      -0.381\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0249)         \\
recibida por servicios&      -0.471\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0740)         \\
otra, cuál          &      -0.116         \\
                    &     (0.368)         \\
horas               &    -0.00160\sym{**} \\
                    &  (0.000514)         \\
% omitida excusado y alcantarillado&           0         \\
  %                   &         (.)         \\
excusado y pozo séptico&       0.241\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0184)         \\
excusado y pozo ciego&       0.431\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0299)         \\
letrina             &       0.496\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0580)         \\
no tiene            &       0.482\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0373)         \\
Ratio dependencia           &     0.00190\sym{***}\\
                    &  (0.000135)         \\
Tamaño              &       0.131\sym{***}\\
                    &   (0.00411)         \\
Urbana              &      -0.257\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0181)         \\
%omitidae\_desempleo         &           0         \\
 % omitida                   &         (.)         \\

Otro empleo no clasificado              &       1.624\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0205)         \\
subempleo           &       1.679\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0227)         \\
%e\_adecuado          &           0         \\
 %                   &         (.)         \\
%sector formal       &           0         \\
  %                  &         (.)         \\
sector informal     &       0.337\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0160)         \\
empleo doméstico    &     -0.0860         \\
                    &    (0.0528)         \\
no clasificados por sector&       0.196\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0315)         \\
%sierra              &           0         \\
 %                   &         (.)         \\
costa               &      -0.120\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0163)         \\
amazonía            &       0.100\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0234)         \\
insular             &      -1.811\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.375)         \\
mujer               &      -0.113\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0226)         \\
año aprobado        &     0.00740         \\
                    &   (0.00388)         \\
%indígena            &           0         \\
   %              &         (.)         \\
afroecuatoriano     &     -0.0872         \\
                    &    (0.0630)         \\
negro               &      -0.107         \\
                    &    (0.0612)         \\
mulato              &      -0.132         \\
                    &    (0.0686)         \\
montubio            &      -0.176\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0374)         \\
mestizo             &      -0.279\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0240)         \\
blanco              &      -0.274\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0631)         \\
otro         &      -0.483         \\
                    &     (0.439)         \\
edad2               &   -0.000279\sym{***}\\
                    & (0.0000354)         \\
edad                &      0.0238\sym{***}\\
                    &   (0.00345)         \\
%casado(a)           &           0         \\
%                    &         (.)         \\

separado(a)         &       0.323\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0791)         \\

divorciado(a)       &       0.318\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0840)         \\

viudo(a)            &       0.408\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0818)         \\

unión libre         &      0.0713\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0172)         \\

soltero(a)          &       0.427\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0796)         \\

Constant            &      -3.727\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.120)         \\
\hline
Observations        &       99218         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\end{tabular}
}
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if your example was working, meaning it starts with `\documentcalss` and ends with `\end{document}`. This makes it easier for people to help you and reduces the chance of anwers that work on one persons setup, but not yours.

Comment: One way is to extend it to three columns, where in the third are values in parenthesis, however I afraid that the table will still be to tall.

Answer (score 2):

The table simply has far too many rows to allow it to fit inside a normal-size page. One way around this is to employ a `longtable` environment, which allows page breaks.

Aligning the numbers in the right-hand column on their decimal markers would be a good idea.

The following screenshot shows just the first few rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}  % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace,dcolumn,longtable,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
{
\singlespacing
\small
%\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{ @{} l d{2.7} @{} }
\toprule
    &\mcc{(1)}\\
    &\mcc{pobreza}\\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.05\), \sym{**} \(p<0.01\), \sym{***} \(p<0.001\)}\\
\endlastfoot

conyuge             &       0.433\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0782)         \\
hijos               &       0.237\sym{***}\\
                    &   (0.00954)         \\
%omitida en arriendo         &           0         \\
%omitida                    &         (.)         \\
anticresis y/o arriendo&      -0.210         \\
                    &     (0.150)         \\
propia y la está pagando&     -0.0977\sym{*}  \\
                    &    (0.0433)         \\
propia y totalmente pagada&     -0.0287         \\
                    &    (0.0199)         \\
cedida              &      -0.381\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0249)         \\
recibida por servicios&      -0.471\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0740)         \\
otra, cuál          &      -0.116         \\
                    &     (0.368)         \\
horas               &    -0.00160\sym{**} \\
                    &  (0.000514)         \\
% omitida excusado y alcantarillado&           0         \\
  %                   &         (.)         \\
excusado y pozo séptico&       0.241\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0184)         \\
excusado y pozo ciego&       0.431\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0299)         \\
letrina             &       0.496\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0580)         \\
no tiene            &       0.482\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0373)         \\
Ratio dependencia           &     0.00190\sym{***}\\
                    &  (0.000135)         \\
Tamaño              &       0.131\sym{***}\\
                    &   (0.00411)         \\
Urbana              &      -0.257\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0181)         \\
%omitidae\_desempleo         &           0         \\
 % omitida                   &         (.)         \\

Otro empleo no clasificado  & 1.624\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0205)         \\
subempleo           &       1.679\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0227)         \\
%e\_adecuado          &           0         \\
 %                   &         (.)         \\
%sector formal       &           0         \\
  %                  &         (.)         \\
sector informal     &       0.337\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0160)         \\
empleo doméstico    &     -0.0860         \\
                    &    (0.0528)         \\
no clasificados por sector&  0.196\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0315)         \\
%sierra              &           0         \\
 %                   &         (.)         \\
costa               &      -0.120\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0163)         \\
amazonía            &       0.100\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0234)         \\
insular             &      -1.811\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.375)         \\
mujer               &      -0.113\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0226)         \\
año aprobado        &     0.00740         \\
                    &   (0.00388)         \\
%indígena            &           0         \\
   %              &         (.)         \\
afroecuatoriano     &     -0.0872         \\
                    &    (0.0630)         \\
negro               &      -0.107         \\
                    &    (0.0612)         \\
mulato              &      -0.132         \\
                    &    (0.0686)         \\
montubio            &      -0.176\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0374)         \\
mestizo             &      -0.279\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0240)         \\
blanco              &      -0.274\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0631)         \\
otro                &      -0.483         \\
                    &     (0.439)         \\
edad\textsuperscript{2}  &   -0.000279\sym{***}\\
                    & (0.0000354)         \\
edad                &      0.0238\sym{***}\\
                    &   (0.00345)         \\
%casado(a)           &           0         \\
%                    &         (.)         \\

separado(a)         &       0.323\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0791)         \\

divorciado(a)       &       0.318\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0840)         \\

viudo(a)            &       0.408\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0818)         \\

unión libre         &      0.0713\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0172)         \\

soltero(a)          &       0.427\sym{***}\\
                    &    (0.0796)         \\

Constant            &      -3.727\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.120)         \\
\midrule
Observations        & \mcc{99218}         \\

\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I have been mentioned in my comment, one way to fit your table on one page is to introduce a new column in table where you collect standard errors (numbers in parenthesis). By using `S` columns defined in the  `siunitx` package numbers can be aligned at decimal points, with `threeparttable` you can add table notes with descriptions of `\tnote`s:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, threeparttable}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \sisetup{input-symbols = {( )},
             table-align-text-post=false,
             table-text-alignment=left}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{My long table}
\label{tab:stat}
    \begin{tabular}{l   S[table-format=-1.6,
                          table-space-text-post={***}]
                        S[table-format= 1.7,
                          table-space-text-pre={(},
                          table-space-text-post={)}]
                    }      
    \toprule
                & {\makecell{(1)\\ pobreza}}
                                        & {\makecell{Standard\\ Error}} \\
    \midrule
conyuge         &  0.433\tnote{***}     &   (0.0782)            \\
hijos           &  0.237\tnote{***}     &   (0.00954)           \\
anticresis y/o arriendo
                & -0.210                &   (0.150)             \\
propia y la está pagando
                & -0.0977\tnote{*}      &   (0.0433)            \\
propia y totalmente pagada
                & -0.0287               &   (0.0199)            \\
cedida          & -0.381\tnote{***}     &   (0.0249)            \\
recibida por servicios
                & -0.471\tnote{***}     &   (0.0740)            \\
otra, cuál      & -0.116                &   (0.368)             \\
horas           & -0.00160\tnote{**}    &   (0.000514)          \\
excusado y pozo séptico
                &  0.241\tnote{***}     &   (0.0184)            \\
excusado y pozo ciego
                &  0.431\tnote{***}     &   (0.0299)            \\
letrina         &  0.496\tnote{***}     &   (0.0580)            \\
no tiene        &  0.482\tnote{***}     &   (0.0373)            \\
Ratio dependencia           
                &  0.00190\tnote{***}   &   (0.000135)          \\
Tamaño          &  0.131\tnote{***}     &   (0.00411)           \\
Urbana          & -0.257\tnote{***}     &   (0.0181)            \\
Otro empleo no clasificado              
                &  1.624\tnote{***}     &   (0.0205)            \\
subempleo       &  1.679\tnote{***}     &   (0.0227)            \\
sector informal     
                &  0.337\tnote{***}     &   (0.0160)            \\
empleo doméstico    
                & -0.0860               &   (0.0528)            \\
no clasificados por sector
                &  0.196\tnote{***}     &   (0.0315)            \\
costa           & -0.120\tnote{***}     &   (0.0163)    \\
amazonía        &  0.100\tnote{***}     &   (0.0234)    \\
insular         & -1.811\tnote{***}     &   (0.375)     \\
mujer           & -0.113\tnote{***}     &   (0.0226)    \\
año aprobado    &  0.00740              &   (0.00388)   \\
afroecuatoriano & -0.0872               &   (0.0630)    \\
negro           & -0.107                &   (0.0612)    \\
mulato          & -0.132                &   (0.0686)    \\
montubio        & -0.176\tnote{***}     &   (0.0374)    \\
mestizo         & -0.279\tnote{***}     &   (0.0240)    \\
blanco          & -0.274\tnote{***}     &   (0.0631)    \\
otro            & -0.483                &   (0.439)     \\
edad2           & -0.000279\tnote{***}  &   (0.0000354) \\
edad            &  0.0238\tnote{***}    &   (0.00345)   \\
separado(a)     &  0.323\tnote{***}     &   (0.0791)    \\
divorciado(a)   &  0.318\tnote{***}     &   (0.0840)    \\
viudo(a)        &  0.408\tnote{***}     &   (0.0818)    \\
unión libre     &  0.0713\tnote{***}    &   (0.0172)    \\
soltero(a)      &  0.427\tnote{***}     &   (0.0796)    \\
Constant        & -3.727\tnote{***}     &   (0.120)     \\
    \midrule
Observations    &  {99218}              &               \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}[para, flushright]
\item[*:]   \(p<0.05\), 
\item[**:]  \(p<0.01\), 
\item[***:] \(p<0.001\)
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{document}
```

[image]